# How to get attribute from xml by PMD

Tags: java, xml, xpath, pmd

I write a rule for xml, and it can find the line matched of xml.
xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sofa="http://schema.alipay.com/sofa/schema/service">
    <sofa:service interface="a.b.c">123</sofa:service>
</beans>
```

xpath expression:

```
//beans/*[local-name() = "sofa:service"]
```

[image]

But in the report, PMD does not provide any value of the matched element.

```
trAdditionalRuleReport = PMD.processFiles(pmdConfiguration, ruleSets, files, new ArrayList<>());
```

[image]

Is there any way to get "interface" in "sofa:service" at only one operation? So that I could avoid to parse the xml manually.

PMD: 6.43.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`local-name()` returns only the name itself, without namespace prefix (`service`). While `name()` returns whole string (`sofa:service`).

So try to rewrite your xpath this way:

```
//beans/*[name() = "sofa:service"]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.